# Find points in a MotionPath between frames (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to find the position of not-keyframe points in a motion path drawn on the stage.
What I can do is to find the position of the mc that is following the object at every frame (red dots)  but I don't know how to access the MotionPath data to try to calculate intermediate positions.

[image: points of path between frames]

Comment: why not just increase main timeline' fps , so the red dots will sit more compact?

Comment: I'm not allowed  to do this. My swf should  be loaded by a container and satisfy strict requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to create your motion path Pro grammatically check this example
[Create a Motion Guide Programmatically](http://www.atksolutions.com/articles/flash_as3_program_motion_guide.html)

Another option if you want to continue working with path tool in flash , is to work on timebased instead of framebased